# ColdFusion HTTP POST large strings

Tags: coldfusion

Has anyone noticed that if you try to post a string that exceeds 1,000,000 characters, it simply does not include the field with the request?

...and doesn't throw()!

eg.

```
<cfscript>
var h = new http( url = "http://...", method = "post" );
h.addParam( type = "formField", name = "a", value = repeatString("a",5000) );
h.addParam( type = "formField", name = "b", value = repeatString("b",1000000) );
h.addParam( type = "formField", name = "c", value = repeatString("c",1000001) );
var p = h.send().getPrefix();
writeDump( var = p, abort = true );
</cfscript>
```

The "a" and "b" fields are present in the form scope of the recipient page.

The "c" field is missing!

ColdFusion 9,0,1,274733 + chf9010002.jar, Mac OS X 10.6.8, Java 1.6.0_31

Edit: **It now works as expected!**

Not sure what has changed? My cf admin configuration remains the same. The only possible candidate I can come up with is a recent Apple Java update. Could that be it?

Comment: Fwiw, a quick test returned all three fields for me.

Comment: ColdFusion servers both sides? I was posting from ColdFusion to PHP. From what I could tell, the max accepted post size, PHP side, was 8mb.

Comment: Yep, same server. But that suggests the problem is not with http. You could sniff/debug the traffic to be sure.

Comment: Strange... It now works fine for me!? Ummm....? The only thing that has changed is a recent apple java update. Perhaps that fixed it?

Comment: I "dunno" :) Since we never figured out which layer was causing the limitation it is impossible to say. But glad to hear it is working now!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify

enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Could also try h.setMethod("post");

Comment: .setMethod("post") has no effect - it's already in the constructor

Comment: A workaround is to write the long string to a temp file, then use `addParam( type = "file" )`. Then on the PHP side, it's in $_FILES, instead of $_POST

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting within CF administrator.

In Coldfusion 9 (this setting has existed for a while, but may exist elsewhere in other versions):

Click on "server settings" group to expand, click on "settings" link (top link). On the settings page:

Maximum size of post data   100 MB (default)
Limits the amount of data that can be posted to the server in a single request. ColdFusion rejects requests larger than the specified limit.

It's interesting that you're hitting a limit right at 100,000 ; sounds like someone got a little lazy with the "bytes" computation. :) At any rate, I'd try tinkering with this setting.

Just an FYI: You'll encounter a similar issue with data truncation on data inserts/updates unless you set your datasource to allow "Long Text Buffer (chr)" greater than the 64,000 default limit.

Comment: Checked my cf admin, it has a value of 100mb. It was failing at >= 1mb. I tried changing the value to 500mb with no effect :(

Comment: Tried setting the value to 1mb, and the receiver page throws a JRun Servlet Error "coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter$PostSizeLimitExceededException", which says to me it only affects incoming requests. Doesn't block outgoing ones.